# Is it possible to make certain parts of a function run before calling it in python?

Tags: python

So right now my code looks like this (haven't added the other two options yet):

```
def what_do(action):
  print "You can eat, move, hunt, or rest."
  for number in resources:
    print number + str(resources[number])
  if action == "eat":
    print "You ate. Hunger restored."
    resources['hunger'] == 0
  if action == "hunt":
    print "You went out and hunted. You found 10 food."
    resources['food'] += 10 
    print resources['food']

what_do(raw_input("What will you do?"))
```

Aside from the other problems this code has, is it possible to print the string I have placed directly after defining the function before calling it?

Comment: Do you not want to move the `print` statement to just before your `def`?

Comment: If you want this code to run *before* you call the function, why is it part of the function at all?

Comment: What I want to happen (I should've specified this, I apologize) is for the code to run indefinitely until the win conditions are met. What I was having difficulty figuring out was how to accomplish this, so I was intending on figuring out how to create a for loop to use the `continue` statement. The answer I was given was able to accomplish what I wanted. Again, I apologize for the vague question, it was my first post on the website. I know I can't hide behind that as an excuse, so again, I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions denote blocks of statements that are run together. Although Python and other languages do define "co-routines" that can pause and resume running, their usage is more advanced than what you seek.

Your pattern for now will be better addressed by splitting your problem into several functions - and one function to coordinate than all - once you have mastered this arrangement and can grow groups of functions at will, you will be able to move on to more sophisticated forms as the need arise. (For example you could also use a class for this, or even orchestrate some co-routines) .

```
def prompt():
    print "You can eat, move, hunt, or rest."

def get_action():
    return raw_input("What will you do?")

def what_do(action):
    for number in resources:
        print number + str(resources[number])
    if action == "eat":
        print "You ate. Hunger restored."
        resources['hunger'] == 0
    if action == "hunt":
        print "You went out and hunted. You found 10 food."
        resources['food'] += 10 
        print resources['food']

def game():
    while True:
        prompt()
        action = get_action()
        what_do(action)

game()
```